Connect a triangular child node with its north corner
I'm drawing part of a tree, and I want child sub-tree to be drawn as a large triangle.
Here's a MWE
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}

\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=4mm,level/.style={sibling distance=8mm/#1},scale=3, every node/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=2pt}]
    
    \node (x) {$x$}
        child {node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3, rounded corners, minimum size=2cm] (ls) {}}
        child {node (y) {$y$}};        
    
    %\draw (x) -- coordinate[above of=x]; %doesn't work
    \coordinate[above of=x] (ax);
    \draw (x) -- (ax);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

which gives the folliwing picture

Thing is... it's ugly : the triangle is not connected by its upper corner, and I have no idea how to do it. Suggestions?

child[child anchor=north] but you won't like that either because the rounding done by PGF is not part of the shape. child[edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode\tikzparentanchor)--([yshift=-.8pt]\tikzchildnode.north)}] looks good to me. See the manual for more options.

It's indeed better looking, and working, but it's still a bit ugly that the angles between the children are not the same. I'm trying on my side to put a completely empty node as a child, and put a triangular node anchored north right above it. So far sgtill ugly

Found the solution: I just have to anchor the node north. I'll answer my own question.

Complete solution working and beautiful-looking solution, thanks @Qrrbrbirlbel
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}

\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=4mm,level/.style={sibling distance=8mm/#1},scale=3, every node/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=2pt}]
    
    \node (x) {$x$}
        child[edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode\tikzparentanchor)--([yshift=-.8pt]\tikzchildnode.north)}] 
            {node[anchor=north,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3, rounded corners, minimum size=2cm] (ls) {}}
        child {node (y) {$y$}};        
    
    \coordinate[above of=x] (ax);
    \draw (x) -- (ax);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


